MutableLivedata isn't triggered after first time
I have a list of categories and every category has subcategories and products.
when I launch the activity the data of subcategories and products are loaded in the UI correctly but when the user click on another category, the API gets the data right but the UI doesn't change
this is the call from the adapter
private fun handleClick(categoryId:Int,categoryName:String) {


    handler(categoryId,categoryName)
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}

this is the fragment that holds the categories and subcategories and products
private fun handleUserClickOnCategory(categoryId: Int, categoryName: String) {
    binding.categoryName.text = "\t"+categoryName
    viewModel.getSubcategoryAndProducts(categoryId)


}

and onViewCreated I observe the change
     viewModel.subCategoryAndProductsResult.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->

            if(it.success =="")
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
           else if (it.error != "") {

                Toast.makeText(context, it.error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else if (it.success != "") {
                var subcategoryList = it.success as ArrayList<Any>
                subcategories = viewModel.getSubCategoriesListFormatted(subcategoryList)
                Log.d("TAG", "onViewCreated: "+subcategories[0].nameEn)
                addSubcategoryAndProducts()

            }
        })
    }

My viewmodel
 var subCategoryAndProductsResult = MutableLiveData<ResultData>()
  fun getSubcategoryAndProducts(categoryId: Int) {
    Log.d("calling api", "Calling products Api")


    subCategoryAndProductsResult=
        categoriesDataSource.getSubcategoryAndProducts(categoryId, 0, 0)


}

the API function
  fun getSubcategoryAndProducts(
    categoryId: Int,
    userId: Int,
    storeId: Int
): MutableLiveData<ResultData> {

    val productsResultData = MutableLiveData<ResultData>()


    val categoriesAndProductsApis =
        retrofitClient.createService(CategoriesAndProductsApis::class.java)


    val response =
        categoriesAndProductsApis.getSubcategoryAndProducts(categoryId, userId, storeId)




                    response.enqueue(object : Callback<ApiResponse> {
                        override fun onResponse(
                            call: Call<ApiResponse>,
                            response: Response<ApiResponse>
                        ) {

                            Log.d("Products ", response.code().toString())
                            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                                val body = response.body()

                                if (body != null && body.statusCode == 200) {
                                    val result = ResultData(body.data!!, "")
                                    productsResultData.setValue(result)


                                    Log.v("Products", result.success.toString())
                                } else {
                                    val result = ResultData("", "Something went wrong")
                                    productsResultData.postValue(result)
                                    Log.v("result", result.error.toString())
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                            val result = ResultData("", "Something went wrong")
                            productsResultData.setValue(result)
                            Log.v("result", result.error.toString())
                        }

                    })







    return productsResultData
}


What does your ResultData class look like? Something is fishy in that else if (it.success != "") block. Is success a String or a List? You’re checking if it equals an empty string but then casting it to a list. And then you never use that list, unless you have trimmed some code.

Also it is unusual to return a new LiveData instance when this function is called. That means every time you change the subcategory, there is a new LiveData you need to observe, but the old ones are still observed redundantly. The MutableLiveData should be in a val property of the ViewModel class, and the Fragment should observe it only once in onViewCreated(). Your function that sets a different subcategory can change the LiveData that is already being observed, and doesn’t need to return anything.

Thank you @Tenfour04....The problem is fixed when I take the variables out of the function and initialized in the class not in the function.
